# How do you set a breadcrumb active or highlight it when it is clicked?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

The Header displays the letters from A to Z. Below is my html code:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
   <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li *ngFor="let letter of letters"><a (click)="onLetter(letter)">{{letter}}</a></li>
  </ol> 
</div>
```

Below is my component code:

```
onLetter(searchStr: string){
   localStorage.setItem('letter', searchStr);
   this._entertainmentService.searchByLetter(searchStr);
   this._router.navigate(['/et/movies/movies']);  
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Store the currently selected letter in a component's property (e.g. `currentLetter`) and use it to dynamically add a class to the `<a>...</a>` tag. For example:

```
<a (click)="onLetter(letter)" [class.active]="letter == currentLetter">
  {{letter}}
</a>
```

Of course you'll have to adapt this code to your situation: you might need to add the class the `<li>` tag instead, or maybe use a different CSS class than `active`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help.